# databinding cannot find method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, gradle, data-binding

I started working with databinding in android and I had a problem.When trying to build a project, an error occurs

Found data binding error(s):
[databinding] {"msg":"cannot find method getMediumStringFromMilli(float) in class com.sgc.weightcontrol.util.DateUtil","file":"B:\projects\weightControl\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_objective.xml","pos":[{"line0":49,"col0":58,"line1":49,"col1":115}]}

My fragment xml (R.layout.fragment_objective)

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <import type="com.sgc.weightcontrol.util.DateUtil" />

        <variable
            name="objective"
            type="com.sgc.weightcontrol.ui.modelUI.ObjectiveUI" />
    </data>

//Container open
      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{`string/start_weight` + DateUtil.getMediumStringFromMilli(objective.startTime)}" " />
//Container close

</layout>
```

DateUtil

```
public class DateUtil {
    private static DateTimeFormatter dateFormatMedium =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM).withLocale(Locale.getDefault());

    public static String getMediumStringFromMilli(long milli){
        LocalDateTime time = Instant.ofEpochMilli(milli).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
        return dateFormatMedium.format(time);
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc0'
    }
```

build.gradle(module)

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Getting binding

```
   FragmentObjectiveBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_objective);
```

My android-studio version = 3.6.2

I tried to clear the cache / restart, change the fragment xml file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes Because Textview android:text accept only string value:

```
android:text="@{String.format(@string/start_weight, DateUtil.getMediumStringFromMilli(objective.startTime))}"
```